# How to select text in a PDF being viewed within Firefox's integrated viewer?

Tags: firefox, pdf, selection, preview, viewer

Firefox includes it's own ***integrated*** PDF viewer.

How does one select text (for copying to the clipboard) from within a PDF being displayed by Firefox's integrated PDF viewer?

Answer (score 1):

It should work just like selecting text on a webpage; mouse over start of selection, left click & drag, and let go. You can then right click your selection to open a context menu to copy it. Tested on Firefox 48.0 with this [PDF](http://unec.edu.az/application/uploads/2014/12/pdf-sample.pdf).

Comment: Thanks.  It's really odd.  Tried it on the same PDF several times.  Didn't work the first couple times, now works as you describe.  The PDF scans clean for malware.  I'll let this question sit for a little while to see if anyone has anything else to contribute.  If not, I'll mark your answer as accepted.  Thanks again, and welcome to Superuser.